# How to extract value using patter and matcher in Java

Tags: java

Hey i am using Pattern and matcher to extract bugId value from given URL.

```
1. url=/prrq/viewReview.do?bugId=bgid12
2. url=/prrq/viewReview.do?queueName=abc&bugId=bgid12
```

This is what i am doing -

```
String getbugIdPattern = ".*[?&]bugId=([^&]+).*";
 Pattern bugIdp = Pattern.compile(getbugIdPattern);
 Matcher bugidm = bugIdp.matcher(url);
 if (bugidm.matches()  ) {
          String bugid = bugidm.group(1);
 }
```

But i am not getting any match result.

Comment: It works for me. What are you getting?

Comment: URL -  /prrq/viewReview.do?bugId=CRRaa75118
matcher Object 
java.util.regex.Matcher[pattern=.*[?&]bugId=([^&]+).* region=0,30 lastmatch=]

Comment: Yeah, that's the Matcher, and doesn't matches() return true, and group(1) return "CRRaa75118"? What is the value of `bugid`?

Comment: Give me sometime. It's working for hardcore url but in method call it's failing. Thanks for help.